# Check if a phrase occurs at least N times in a document using only REGEX

Tags: regex

so I have, for example, this toy text/code:

```py
db.session.commit()
#rollback
user = User.query.get(1)
print("Some printouts") 
db.session.rollback()
print("\nCommit the change:")
db.session.commit()
```

I want to write a JavaScript based regular expression to check if `db.session.commit()` is written at least, for example, 2 times. If it's written fewer than 2 times, the match should fail (I would use this for testing the code). This should work for any N times (2, 3, ...).

I tried gazillion of combinations on Regex101, with {} repetition and (non)capturing groups but nothing worked well so far. I am still learning. I managed to get this far: https://regex101.com/r/V4RPcb/4 but the moment you put something in the empty space between two commits (or anywhere else), it fails. I haven't found similar questions anywhere else (which could also mean it is trivial lol). I know I could use a for loop, but in this case, I can only use regex.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Which environment do you run the regex in? Shell? Java? Perl? Python? Some other language? Counting matches will be way more efficient than matching the part of the input multiple times.

Comment: I am using someone else's testing engine and they are using JavaScript as mentioned in the question. I know there are other ways to do it, but in this specific instance I can only input a regular expression, and I don't have access to their entire code.

Answer (score 1):

You can match the whole line and capture it in group 1. Then match a newline followed by 0+ whitespace chars and use a backreference `\1` to match the same again.

```
^(db\.session\.commit)\r?\n\s*\1
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3rKFtq/1)

If you want to match it 2 times for the example data when there can also be other lines in between:

```
^(db\.session\.commit\(\))(?:\r?\n(?!\1).*)*\r?\n\1
```

*In parts*

- `^` Start of line
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `db\.session\.commit\(\)` Match `db.session.commit()`
- `)` Close group
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\r?\n` Match a newline
  - `(?!\1).*` Assert what is directly to the right is not what is captured in group 1 using a back reference. If that is the case, match the whole line.
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times
- `\r?\n` Match a newline
- `\1` Backreference to what is captured in group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9nQeuf/1)

Comment: @mishsx Please read the question again `I want to write a JavaScript based regular expression to check if db.session.commit() is written at least 2 times.`

Comment: In that case, why are we complicating things. Instead, we can just get done with `/(db\.session\.commit\s?\r?){2}/g` Please correct me if I am wrong here. But I was able to match at least 2 occurrences of the said text with my regex.

Comment: Well, that regex does not match the content in the example regex link https://regex101.com/r/K7orGp/1 And even if you remove the whitespaces in between, it still requires a whitespace char at the end which will not match this https://regex101.com/r/p2W1AD/1

Comment: Hi, this works, but like in my case only when there are empty spaces in between. The moment you add some code in between it doesn't work: https://regex101.com/r/3rKFtq/2
Also, is it possible to do it for N times - not just 2 (2 was just in my example)

Comment: @Irma Then you have to use the second pattern `^(db\.session\.commit)(?:\r?\n(?!\1).*)*\r?\n\1` https://regex101.com/r/YVNekK/1

Comment: thanks. Sorry I didn't see the regex in your main post addressing the "code in between" case. I was just wondering how I would do it for N times. For example, check if db.session.commit() occurs at least 3 times (and so on). Would/Could you concatenate these somehow?

Comment: @Irma You might do it like this where the `{2}` at the end can be 3 or 4 etc `^(db\.session\.commit)(?:(?:\r?\n(?!\1).*)*\r?\n\1){2}` https://regex101.com/r/HDhDtf/1

Comment: Oh yes, you're the best. There comes that {N} I have been trying (unsuccessfully) for quite a long time. Now I just need to wrap my head around it. Thank you N times!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
(db\.session\.commit\(\))[\s\S]*?\1

(db\.session\.commit\(\))  # matches: db.session.commit() in capture group 1
[\s\S]*?                   # matches any character including newline non-greedily 0 or more times
\1                         # matches capture group 1, i.e. db.session.commit()
```

The above should find any two occurrences of `db.session.commit()` anywhere in the string, whether on the same line or not.

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UUAxVC/1/)